# 2D coordinates from 1D array

Tags: arrays, lua

So basically I'm converting the array index to 2d coordinates.

What I'm trying is the 2D reverse here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/212813/199992

But on the division part for the x (in my case the width is 3), it's returning a double/float, which make sense since (2 / 3) isn't a whole number.

Should I be rounding x?

My code (Lua) is:

```
for i=1, 9 do
    local x = i % 3
    local y = i / 3
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you should be rounding x (down), the same for y:

```
local x = math.floor(i % 3)
local x = math.floor(i / 3)
```

But you should either count from 0..8 instead (and add 1 to x and y to be 1-based), or subtract 1 from i like this (this is how I usually do it in lua):

```
for i=1, 9 do
    local x = math.floor((i - 1) % 3) + 1 -- 1, 2 or 3
    local y = math.floor((i - 1) / 3) + 1 -- 1, 2 or 3
end
```

Comment: `math.floor` isn't needed when applying modulus on integers.

Comment: yeah, but it only works if you are using lua 5.3 and up: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#8.1

Comment: More simple form: `local x = (i-1)%3 + 1; local y = (i-x)/3 + 1`